# Why can't internal stages be cloned in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My understanding is that internal stages cannot be cloned in Snowflake.

Why is this ? It must be a design choice, but what would be the downside of allowing the cloning of an internal stage ? If I clone a schema, then the databases contained therein will be cloned. It seems obvious that in such cases we would also want to internal stage(s) to be cloned, but presumably there is a good reason why this doesn't happen ?

Comment: The following Snowflake link also says the internal stages cannot be cloned ,https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-clone.html

Comment: Can't say I know the reason but if you have a use case for cloning stages, each table has its own built-in stage. When Snowflake clones a table, it does clone that table stage (but not the load history for the table stage).

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Cloud Services layer and the design behind the metadata pointers. The pointers point to micro-partitions that make up a table. Is there a specific requirement you're after?